# Save cookies immediately in dwb

Tags: browser, cookies

I use the dwb browser and I would like to share the cookies between the different windows.

So, I set the file-sync-interval setting to 0, but if I open a new window, the cookies are not saved.

I have to close a window for the cookies to be saved.

How can I configure dwb to have the cookies saved immediately so that they are shared between the different windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if it set file-sync-interval to 1 but it seems to write the cookies every second which is not very efficient.